# Push notifications are not working on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

I fallowed this tutorial:http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12
Everything is ok, notification approve is showed. But notifications are not arriving. My iphone is connected to wi-fi and notifications are allowed.
Notifications from my application work on other iPhones!
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check it Settings > Notifications > (App name) and then just turn it on.